# VBA - Mailmerge gives old data from a (few) save(s) back

Tags: excel, vba, mailmerge

Using office 2007. I have an Excel sheet with some macros, and these macros are creating a word document using mailmerge. The problem is, that when I execute the mailmerge for the first time, I get data from the excel sheet from a save ago. Only after the first mail merge if I save the Excel sheet again (Yes I also saved it prior to the first mailmerge) will the second mailmerge be with the right information.

The mailmerge performed is always over just one line in the Excel document. So it creates one output document. Imagine this was the Excel line:

```
NAME    INVOICENR   AMOUNT
Peter   12345-001   400
```

I now change the data to:

```
NAME    INVOICENR   AMOUNT
Nicolas 12345-004   3400
```

I save the document and run the macro to run the mail merge. I will now get a created document with Peter in it.
If I now save the document again and run the macro again, I will get the document with Nicolas in it.

The only thing I found online about it, is this: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/204542/en-us but it refers to Office 2000 so I don't know if it's actually relevant.

The macro that's being run is here:

```
Sub RunSingleLine(template As String)
    Dim CurrentRow As Integer
    CurrentRow = 1 'Never needs to be anything else.

    Dim wd As Object
    Dim wdocSource As Object

    Dim strWorkbookName As String
    strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If wd Is Nothing Then
        Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set wdocSource = wd.Documents.Open(template)

    wdocSource.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = 0

    wdocSource.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
            Name:=strWorkbookName, _
            AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
            Revert:=False, _
            Format:=0, _
            Connection:="Data Source=" & strWorkbookName & ";Mode=Read", _
            SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Mergetable$`"
            'Mergetable is a worksheet with the necessary info for the merge

    With wdocSource.MailMerge
        .Destination = 0
        .SuppressBlankLines = True
        With .DataSource
            .FirstRecord = CurrentRow
            .LastRecord = CurrentRow
        End With
        .Execute Pause:=False
    End With

    wd.Visible = True
    wdocSource.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Set wdocSource = Nothing
    Set wd = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: @pnuts wdocSrouce is the original word template which should remain untouched, so changes (if any) to it should not be saved. The resulting document is a different object not in this bit of code.

Comment: I haven't tsted this code, but when you merge to a new document, the new document will become the activedocument and will remain open unless you close it. Because you do not close the active document, or quit Word (you are just dsiposing of the programming objects wdocSource and wd, not the real objects they reference), I wonder whether you are actually seeing the same document when you next invoke, and not seeing the new Active Document created in the next merge.